# Python reading multiple value in multiprocessing

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I've been trying to build a simple multiprocessing program that capture value of X in certain time, skipping value that not in read time. 
This is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from time import sleep

def f(conn):
    x=0
    for i in xrange(0,20):
       x+=1
       sleep(0.1)
       conn.send(x)
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        print parent_conn.recv()   
        sleep(0.4)
    p.join()
```

Roughly, what i'm expect from code above is this:

```
>>>
4
8
16
20
```

but instead, the IDLE gave me this output:

```
>>>
1
2
3
4
5
```

And so on till it reach 20.
Is there any command to clear the buffer? or similar thing?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `recv()` gets the next value in the pipe and not the last one.

So, after 4 iterations, `f` did `send` 4 items into `pipe`, so the pipe looks like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

and the main process will `recv` `1`:

```
2, 3, 4
```

after another 4 iterations of `send`:

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

and the main process `recv`es `2`. In order to receive only the last one you need to empty the pipe first:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from time import sleep

def f(conn):
    x=0
    for i in xrange(0,20):
       x+=1
       sleep(0.1)
       conn.send(x)
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        sleep(0.4)
        # `recv` all values, keep only the last one
        last = None
        while parent_conn.poll():
            last = parent_conn.recv()
        print(last)
    p.join()
```

Comment: so, i should use poll() to clear the pipe. but how that's possible? when the poll() become False? i mean it should be at the end of 20 right? or i missing something here? it's works obviously, but i just baffled how this thing work. thank you

Comment: @aji `poll` checks if there are still elements in the pipe which can be received, so you can understand it as `has_elements`. If `poll` becomes false you stop the while loop. The emptying of the pipe is done with the repeating `recv`.